# Binding IsVisible property to my VIewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some entry, and on focus of that entry I want to show my cancel button.

Here is the xaml:

```
 <RelativeLayout>
                <controls:StandardEntry
                        x:Name="mainEntry"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        BorderColor="Gray"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        CornerRadius="15"
                        Placeholder="Search..."
                        TextColor="LightGray"
                        HeightRequest="10"
                        Padding="35,0"
                        FontSize="Default"
                        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height,Factor=0,Constant=40}"
                        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.7,Constant=0}">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Focused" Command="{Binding SearchBarFocusedCommand}"/>
                        <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Unfocused" Command="{Binding SearchBarUnfocusedCommand}"/>
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </controls:StandardEntry>
                <Image 
                        Source="Invest_Search_Icon.png" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=mainEntry, Property=X,Factor=1,Constant=10}"
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=mainEntry, Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=10}"/>
                <Image 
                        Source="Invest_Search_Icon.png"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=mainEntry, Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=-25}"
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=mainEntry, Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=10}"/>
                <Button 
                        Text="Cancel" 
                        TextColor="Gray"
                        IsVisible="{Binding CancelButtonIsVisible}"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        CornerRadius="10" 
                        HeightRequest="40" 
                        Margin="0,0,50,0"
                        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=mainEntry, Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=mainEntry, Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=0}"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

As you see Imusing EventToCommand Behavior, which is work ok (it enters into my command methods). In my VM:

```
    public class InvestViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public InvestViewModel()
        {
            SetDefaultContent();
            SearchBarFocusedCommand = new Command(() => OnSearchBarFocused());
        }

        private void OnSearchBarUnfocused()
        {
            CancelButtonIsVisible = false;
        }

        private void OnSearchBarFocused()
        {
           CancelButtonIsVisible = false;
        }

        private void SetDefaultContent()
        {
            CancelButtonIsVisible = true;
        }

       

        private bool cancelButtonIsVisible;
        public bool CancelButtonIsVisible
        {
            get => cancelButtonIsVisible;
            set
            {
                cancelButtonIsVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => CancelButtonIsVisible);
            }
        }

        public ICommand CancelClickCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand SearchBarFocusedCommand { get; set; }
    }
```

So the flow:

1. On page loading, first SetDefaultContent() => `CancelButtonIsVisible = true;`
2. On Entry focused, hide cancel button OnSearchBarFocused() => `CancelButtonIsVisible = false;`

Apparently, SetDefaultContent **is working**.

**It doesnt work** my focus method, when I focused nothing happens, there is still visible cancel button.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You say that the command actually gets executed (I assume you've set a breakpoint in OnSearchBarFocused and it's hit?), so apparently the vm is properly set to the binding context (your code doesn't show where that happens). Your code also doesn't show your implementation of RaisePropertyChanged, so it's hard to know if that's working correctly. Also, have you considered just using the SearchBar control?

Answer (score 0):

### Option-1

The simpler option would be to bind `IsVisible` property on 'Cancel' button to `IsFocused` property on entry (mainEntry) control using named reference.

```
<Button Text="Cancel" 
     IsVisible="{Binding IsFocused, Source={x:Reference mainEntry}, 
                     Converter={StaticResource NegateBooleanConverter}}" />
```

You can implement a converter that will negate the boolean value for you. Alternatively you can use triggers as well.

```
public class NegateBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

### Option-2

Another option is to bind `IsFocused` with a view-model property.

Create a property with setter in viewmodel

```
public bool IsEntryFocused
{
   set
   {
      CancelButtonIsVisible = !value;
   }
}
```

and set up the binding in view

```
<controls:StandardEntry
     x:Name="mainEntry"
     ...
     IsFocused="{Binding IsEntryFocused}"
```